# Fragment content not showing using tab select call

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My profile" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/realtime_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the app starts I want to show some content in the fragment element. So I have created two fragment layouts that should be shown based on the tab that the user have selected. In `onCreateView`:

```
 tabslayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)

    tabslayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object :
        TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab)
        {
            val manager = childFragmentManager
            val trans = manager.beginTransaction()
            trans.replace(R.id.realtime_fragment,getNewFragment(tab.position))
            trans.commit()
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab)
        {
            println("Unselected")
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab)
        {
            println("Reselected")
        }
    })

private fun getNewFragment(tab_id :Int): Fragment
{
    return when(tab_id)
    {
        0 ->
        {
            FragmentRealtime()
        }
        1 ->
        {
            FragmentTripPlanner()
        }
        else ->
        {
            FragmentRealtime()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I do this since I want to show the "My profile" fragment content:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    tabslayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()
}
```

But the content that should be displayed when that tab is selected does not show before I press "Settings" which is the second tab, and then press "My profile". Hence, it does not seem to care about the select() call that I do. What is the problem here?
If I try:

```
tabslayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()
tabslayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()
```

I just get an exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:907)
```

Thanks for any help and guidance!

Comment: Hello: I suggest you use ViewPager2 wtih TabLayout. I have a recent project where I create a Tab Layout and and viewpager2. the viewpager2 has an adapter that is responsible for showing the fragments @araw

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tab at position 0 is selected initially by default before the listener gets registered and `onTabSelected` may not called when selecting an already selected tab. So, you need to manually replace the fragment or call `OnTabSelectedListener`'s `onTabSelected()` method for the first time. Alternatively, put the code in `onTabReselected` instead of `onTabSelected`. Also as @i_o suggests `TabLayout + ViewPager/ViewPager2` might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then I just get the exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:907) for some reason